# ERROR: syntax error at or near "from" when using count and finding percentage

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
with result as
(
select ((count(case when fsr.position <= 3 and fse.has_clicked = 'yes' THEN search_id END)
        /
        count(*) from fb_search_results)::float) * 100
from fb_search_results fsr JOIN fb_search_events fse on fsr.result_id = fse.search_id
)select * from result
```

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "from"

I have no idea why the error is coming, can someone help?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  Your intended logic is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: `(` - `)` something, in the WITH clause.

Comment: The first `from fb_search_results` must go.